# null check throws unary operator error

Tags: bash

I am tying to check if a variable is null, It throws the below error. I have tried the below combinations but it says the same error. I am trying to find out the files in a folder

```
cmd="ls -tm"
output=$($cmd)

echo $output // doesn't print out anything as the folder is empty

if [  $output != "" ];
```

For the below one it goes to the loop

```
if[ -z $output ];
```

Error output:

```
line 25: [: !=: unary operator expected
```

Any suggestions for handling this?

Comment: You need a space between `if` and `[`. And can you show a little more of the code?

Comment: Ya there is a space between if and [.

Comment: You need to show your more accurately and with a little more detail. There's very little here to go by. If I put `if [ -z $output ]; then echo foo ; fi` in bash, for example, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using  `if [ "$output" != "" ];` instead of `if [ $output != "" ];`?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Quine's suggestion, if $output is null, your if statement expands to

```
if [ != "" ];
```

which makes bash think an argument is missing.  Quoting the parameter name overcomes this.